# how to tell gradle to wait untill the commandLine process is excuted?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, devops

Below is my code and i am fetching the imagename and imagetag from a json file called manifest.json
i want the docker save commandLine process to wait for sometime for each key and value to complete the saving process

```
class SaveTask extends Exec {
  def manifestFile = new File("$rootDir/manifest","manifest.json")
  SaveTask() {
   
     new JsonSlurper().parseText(manifestFile.text).get("services").each { key,value ->
     
     commandLine "bash", "-c", "docker save ${key}:${value} | gzip > ${key}.tar.gz"
     
}
}
task saveImageA(type: SaveTask)
```

can someone help me to  implement  the above scenario?

Comment: You are probably better making a plugin, then you can create a save task per image, and a task `saveAll` which `dependsOn` them all